# Bind the text property of multiple TextBoxes using only one variable and one event on MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to use the `SelectFile` event of a single `Select` button and the `outputFolderPath` binding to set the value for several TextBoxes in an WPF application. 
How can I do that?

Here is the code on the `MainWindow.xaml`:

```
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="10 10 0 0">
                        <TextBlock Margin="5 0 0 5" Text="First File:" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        <TextBox Margin="0 0 0 5" Padding="2" x:Name="firstFilePath" Text="{Binding outputFolderPath}"/>

                        <TextBlock Margin="5 0 0 5" Text="Second File:" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        <TextBox Margin="0 0 0 5" Padding="2" x:Name="secondfilePath" Text="{Binding outputFolderPath}"/>
                    </StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="10 30 0 0">
                        <Button Margin="0 0 0 0" Content="Select" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" Click="SelectFile"/>
                        <Button Margin="0 23 0 0" Content="Select" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" Click="SelectFile"/>
                    </StackPanel>
```

And this one on the `MainWindow.xaml.xs`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string outputFolderPath { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void SelectFile(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog().Value)
        {
            outputFolderPath = openFileDialog.FileName;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(outputFolderPath)));
        }
    }
}
```

The WPF app looks like this:
[[image]

Comment: Of course you can bind multiple textboxes to a single property. But that would also mean that those multiple textboxes would share the **same** value/text. (Wanting multiple textboxes to be bound to the same property while having their own different values would require something like quantum computers exploiting superposition... ;-b)

Comment: Could you specify why there can be only one variable?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't have to be only one. I'd really like to have just one, since my program needs so much input info, and I'd like to shrink the number of variables.
Don't know if I made myself clear. If I haven't, please ask! My english is kind of rusted hahah

Answer (score 0):

Implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` like below and use the event to notify change in property.

You need to have two properties to contain two different values.

Sample code -

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
  {

    private string outputFolderPath;
    public string OutputFolderPath
    {
        get { return outputFolderPath; }
        set
        {
            outputFolderPath = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("OutputFolderPath");
        }
    }

    private string secondOutputFolderPath;
    public string SecondOutputFolderPath
    {
        get { return secondOutputFolderPath; }
        set
        {
            secondOutputFolderPath= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SecondOutputFolderPath");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For styling and templating purposes, I would recommend you to provide two dependency properties which you can then bind your `TextBox`es to.

On your `MainWindow` C# class, define the following read-only dependency properties:

```
#region FirstFile dependency property

public string FirstFile 
{
    get => (string)GetValue(FirstFileProperty);
    private set => SetValue(FirstFilePropertyKey, value);
}

private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey FirstFilePropertyKey = 
    DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(nameof(FirstFile), 
        typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow));

public static readonly DependencyProperty FirstFileProperty = 
    FirstFilePropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

#endregion

#region SecondFile dependency property

public string SecondFile 
{
    get => (string)GetValue(SecondFileProperty);
    private set => SetValue(SecondFilePropertyKey, value);
}

private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey SecondFilePropertyKey = 
    DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(nameof(SecondFile), 
        typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow));

public static readonly DependencyProperty SecondFileProperty = 
    SecondFilePropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

#endregion
```

Now, bind your text boxes to these dependency properties, like the following:

```
<TextBox Margin="0 0 0 5" Padding="2" x:Name="firstFilePath" Text="{Binding FirstFile}"/>
<TextBox Margin="0 0 0 5" Padding="2" x:Name="secondfilePath" Text="{Binding SecondFile}"/>
```

Dependency properties provide the necessary notification mechanisms for WPF, which ease our work. They are preferred for binding scenarios, when possible.